# Ruby on rails form_tag empty commit value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I press push button with params[:commit] == 'User'. But in controller action value always = "" (empty) . What am I doint wrong?

Controller class

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController 

    def show
    end

    def panel
        puts "Params ============================================= " 
        if params[:commit] == 'Users'
            puts "Users ============================================= " 
            puts params[:commit]
        elsif params[:commit] == 'Projects'
            puts "Projects ============================================= " 
            puts params[:commit]
        else              
            puts "ELSE  ============================================"
            puts params[:commit] 
        end
    end

end
```

view panel.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag url_for(action: 'panel'), method: "post" do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'User' %>
<% end %>
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'admin#show' 

  get  '/panel', to: "admin#panel"
end
```

logs

```
Processing by AdminController#panel as HTML
Params ============================================= 
ELSE  ============================================

  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering admin/panel.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered admin/panel.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 523)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 6.5ms | Allocations: 2745)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 12.0ms | Allocations: 3047)
```

Comment: What params are you getting in logs?

Comment: `post "/panel", to: "admin#panel"`

Comment: I added this before I read your comment. Thanks for your repliy. Do you know why controller instance not changing it's value after call form_tag?